# How to insert an element into a sublist in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list in form of

```
m = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, ],
    [5, 6, 7, 8, ],
]
```

I want to insert a new element into the first sublist, how can I do that?

Comment: Insert _where_? `m[0].append(99)` will append a new item or `m[0].insert(2, 99)` will insert at an arbitrary point.

Comment: thank you for  answering, I want to insert a new element into the first sublist, index 0